# Returning website screenshot based on Custom Field

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to return a screenshot from websites using this

```
<img src="<?php echo 'http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/'.urlencode('http://domain.com/').'?w=200' ?>" />
```

This works fine for the current domain.com, I am trying to combine this with a custom field where I normally enter

```
<?php the_field('website'); ?>
```

I have tried the following

```
<img src="<?php echo 'http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/'.urlencode(the_field('website'); ').'?w=200' ?>" />
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks
Richard

Comment: As shown below, you need to remove the semi colon and use `get_the_field()` so the custom field result is returned and not immediately echoed as when using `the_field()`

Answer (score 0):

i think there is an error -

```
<img src="<?php echo 'http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/'.urlencode(the_field('website'); ').'?w=200' ?>"  />
```

it should be

```
<img src="<?php echo 'http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/'.urlencode(the_field('website').'?w=200' ?>" alt="" />
```

And if this not work.

I think you use the_field('website') function which actually not return result you can try

this code.

```
<img src="<?php echo 'http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/'.urlencode(get_the_field('website').'?w=200' ?>" alt=""  />
```